# AssertionError on Scala 2.13.10 project when not using any assert statement

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm getting the following error code when running `sbt clean assembly` on a Scala 2.13.10 project using JVM 1.8 and IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition). I think it's not caused by any assert included in my code.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
  List(method apply$mcI$sp, method apply$mcI$sp)
     while compiling: D:\repo\git\external\project9\src\main\scala\es\package\graph\KNNGraphBuilder.scala
        during phase: globalPhase=specialize, enteringPhase=explicitouter
     library version: version 2.13.10
    compiler version: version 2.13.10
  reconstructed args: 

  last tree to typer: Ident(x1)
       tree position: line 270 of D:\repo\git\external\project9\src\main\scala\es\package\graph\KNNGraphBuilder.scala
            tree tpe: x1.type
              symbol: case value x1
   symbol definition: case val x1: (Int, es.package.graph.NeighborsForElement) (a TermSymbol)
      symbol package: es.package.graph
       symbol owners: value x1 -> method $anonfun$addElements -> method addElements -> class GroupedNeighborsForElement
           call site: method neighborsWithComparisonCountOfGroup in class GroupedNeighborsForElementWithComparisonCount in package graph

== Source file context for tree position ==
```

```scala
   267
   268   def addElements(n:GroupedNeighborsForElement):Unit=
   269   {
   270     for ((k,v) <- n.neighbors)
   271       addElementsOfGroup(k,v)
   272   }
   273
```

`n.neighbors` is returning `Map[Int,NeighborsForElement] here`. Other relevant code can be found below:

```scala
  def addElementsOfGroup(groupId:Int, n:NeighborsForElement):Unit=
  {
    getOrCreateGroup(groupId).addElements(n)
  }

  private def getOrCreateGroup(groupId:Int):NeighborsForElement=
  {
    val g=neighbors.get(groupId)
    if (g.isDefined) return g.get
    val newGroup=new NeighborsForElement(numNeighbors)
    neighbors(groupId)=newGroup
    return newGroup
  }
```

This is the `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "project9"

version := "0.1"

organization := "es.package"

scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

val sparkVersion = "3.3.1"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "apache-snapshots" at "https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong with this code? Thanks

Comment: The assertion is thrown from the compiler - did you used some compiler plugin like Better Monadic For?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't think I'm using any compiler plugin. I included the content of the build.sbt file for reference.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in a compiler, if you are able to reproduce it without Spark, I would suggest reporting it on GH to compiler team.

Comment: I suspect that it is due to fact how pattern-matching in for-comprehension works (you have `(k,j) <- ` there) - it's `withFilter` (checking that value actually matches the pattern) combined with `map`/`flatMap`/`foreach` (which uses partial function without handing unmatched cases) and perhaps there is some regression in 2.13.10 with this case. Try splitting it to `for { pair <- n.neighbors; (k,v) = pair } ...` to change what code is generated inside for-comprehension. If it helps and you can reproduce a minimal example it would be nice to report a bug to compiler team.

Comment: Thanks again. Splitting it didn't work. It only compiled after downgrading scala to version 2.12.2. I checked that all versions >= 2.12.3 cause the same error.